# Lists: Circle progress bar as column view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Build in the SharePoint list classes is the option to display percent values as a progress bar.

My idea is to show it as a round progress circle instead (like the image below).

Can this be achieved with the limited CSS support of SharePoint lists? Maybe with the SVG path command?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using JSON column formatting capabilities.

Check this sample available in GitHub list formatting samples repository:

[Doughnut Chart](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/number-doughnut-chart)

[image]

---

---

**Additional formatting samples**:

1. [Number Battery](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/number-battery)

   [image]
2. [Number Gauge](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/number-gauge)

   [image]

Comment: Thx, I totally skipped the columns section in the GitHub and focused on the view section.

Comment: @Ganesh - have you come across any way to display an ‘arrow progress bar’?  There is detailed question here that recently had a 100 point bounty that expired, but no answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75406639/nested-child-elements-not-displaying-in-json-column-formatting-in-microsoft-list

Comment: I will have a look and get back to you.

Comment: Hi @user1063287, I have replied on the question you posted on StackOverflow. Let me know if it works for you.